# CFDictionary returns null

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

I'm attempting to use Core Foundation for the first time and I must be missing something.
I am attempting to use NSObjects as my keys and values for a CFMutableDictionaryRef.

I have the following test app:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString* key = @"testKey";
    NSObject* item = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    const CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks keyCB = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks;
    const CFDictionaryValueCallBacks valCB = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks;

    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &keyCB, &valCB);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(dict, item, key);
    NSLog(@"[CH] added = %@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, key));
    NSLog(@"[CH] size = %ld", CFDictionaryGetCount(dict));


}
```

The output:

> 2011-07-14 16:47:40.568 TestCoreFoundation[61343:903] [CH] added =
>   (null) 2011-07-14 16:47:40.578 TestCoreFoundation[61343:903] [CH] size
>   = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the call to CFDictionaryAddValue backwards. It's dict, key, and then value:

```
CFDictionaryAddValue(dict, key, item);
```

Other than that, it looks fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't see that! Thank you so much!